# iOS Google maps 1.9 - My location icon

Tags: ios, google-maps

I just updated my iOS app with the latest google maps version 1.9. It happens that sometimes the "current location" icon gets this white rectangle around it. Any clue why?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find anything about this?

Comment: Are you both using the same SDK? and also is it 1.9.0 or 1.9.1?

Comment: I get this problem on both versions

Comment: This is a known issue in the iOS simulator: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7315. Are you facing this on devices as well?