# GMSMapView default current location image with transparency in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

The current location image in Google Maps SDK for iOS is opaque for iOS 8. How to change the image or use the same but with transparency?

[image: Screenshot of GMSMapView with My Location]

Comment: Create your own marker and handle the tap on the "my location" button yourself - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#ac0e0171b811e839d9021800ca9fd33f4

Comment: Possibly related in Google Maps API bug reports: [Issue 7315](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7315)

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368913/ios-google-maps-1-9-my-location-icon

Answer (score 6):

This is a weird behaviour on the simulator, but it renders the marker with transparency on the actual device.

On iOS Simulator:

[image]

On iPhone 6 Plus:

[image]